# How to set the default ownership of all directories to myself?

Tags: macos, permission

After downloading angular globally I got an EMACS error that said I didn't have ownership to certain directories. I manually set the owner from root to myself.

This has happened again now that I'm installing postgres via homebrew:

```
You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.   
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/doc 
/usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1
```

Why am I not the owner of everything by default? I am the only admin on this computer. I would like to make sure I am the only admin with all ownership. Is there a way to change that so I don't have to manually reset the ownership every time I download something new?

Comment: You shouldn't have to manually reset the ownership every time you install, so something is clearly wrong with your setup to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Based on

> I manually set the owner from root to myself.

It seems that you are downloading/installing software as root user, did you enabled *root* access four your own user? If yes you must disable it.

Comment: A lot of software gets installed as root, you don‘t need to enable the root user for this to happen.